# Static web content not accessible after NGINX rewrite

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, camunda

I have a centos7 vm in which I deployed two spring services : tasklist (8082) and operate (8081), those two services are available via browser (I can go to http://[host-ip]:8081 (host-ip : vm ip address) via my browser and get access to the application) :

[image]

but when I tried to reverse proxy those ports (8081 & 8082) I can not get access to the static content when I inspect I got those errors :
[image]

here is my nginx configuration :

```
server{
       listen 445;
       listen [::]:445;

       location /operate/ {
           rewrite ^/operate/(.*)$ /$1 break;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
       }

       location /tasklist/ {
           rewrite ^/tasklist/(.*)$ /$1 break;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it like this:

```
location ~ ^/operate/(.*)$ {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/$1;
       }

location ~ ^/tasklist/(.*)$ {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/$1;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }

location /static {
  root /var/www/html/static; # Adjust to your actual folder
}
```